# Error Message: Invalid 'row.names' length while renaming rowname

Tags: r

I am trying to rename the rows of my dataframe and keep getting the error message

> .rowNamesDF <- (x, value = value) : invalid 'row.names' length'

For example: This is my data:

| Continent | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Eur | 1 | A |
| Asia | 2 | B |
| Africa | 3 | C |

**Code for the data**

```
df<-data.frame(a=c("Aus","Asia","Eur"), b=1:3, c=LETTERS[1:3])
```

**I have tried**

```
rownames(df)<-df[,1]
```

I can't figure out why the error message is showing.

Comment: You are assigning columns b and c as rownames  Do you need `row.names(df) <- df[,1]`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to akrun's comment here is the code to remove column a

```
df1 <- df[,-1]           # new dataframe df1 with removed column a
rownames(df1) <- df[,1]  # code identical to akrun's comment
```

Output:

```
     b c
Aus  1 A
Asia 2 B
Eur  3 C
```